# Function .name property

Tags: javascript, function, expression

Why does the first snippet print `'bar'` and the second `''`?

```js
const bar = () => {}
console.log(bar.name) // 'bar'
```

```js
const bar = 1 && (() => {})
console.log(bar.name) // ''
```

I also note that the same behavior occurs with traditional (ie. non-arrow) functions.

Comment: `function.name` only works for unnamed functions when they are directly assigned to a property or variable.

Comment: For name inference to occur, the function expression has to be directly assigned to the `const`. When it becomes indirect (in your case, because it's the operand to `&&`), the inference doesn't occur.

Comment: I'm not getting the reason for the downvotes. This isn't obvious and is tricky to research.

Comment: I think reading more about the logical AND assignment operator (&&=) would help this be a little clearer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND_assignment

Comment: `&&=` is not used in this question.